# Firefox plugin to learn about technologies used by other web sites

Tags: web-development, firefox, research

Is there a FireFox plugin that tells you what web server (httpd, Tomcat, IIS), platforms (Drupal, WordPress, Rails, PHP, .NET, Java) and client-side (JavaScript, HTML5, Flex) technologies a particular web site uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wappalyzer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/) will do this for [many tools](http://wappalyzer.com/about/#list).
Note that some may not be possible, and also that there are ways to obfuscate some of them(eg. installing to non-standard locations) that might break detection, depending upon the particular method used.